# Events not getting attached to dynamically created elements on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, cordova

`list[i].fnctn` - Contains the name of the function that I want to attach to the click event handler. I have these functions globally defined within the same `js` file

```
function createList(list){
    var parentID = $("#content_nav ul");
    var len = list.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var anchorElement = jQuery('<a />',{text:list[i].text});
        var liElement = jQuery('<li />',{"class":"navlink_"+(i+1),id:"navlink_"+(i+1)});
        //anchorElement.attr('onclick',list[i].fnctn+"()"); - Works fine on desktop browsers but doesn't work on mobile devices. (Mobile devices are my target platform

        anchorElement.on('click',{funct:list[i].fnctn},function(event) {
            return window[event.data.funct](event);
        });
        liElement.append(anchorElement);
        parentID.append(liElement);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on desktop browser. But it does not work when I deploy it to the mobile device using phone gap.

What is the problem?

The devices I tried on are - Samsung Google Nexus S (ICS 4.0.0) iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s (Simulator), Android simulator.

PS : Let me know if there is any other better way of doing this. What I am doing right now is, I take name of the function to be assigned to the event handler from JSON (as a string) and then apply it using the code above. I don't know if thats the best practice. Please help :)

Comment: Are you calling the code AFTER the DOM has loaded or might it be running  before items like parentID are there?  Things take longer to load on mobile.  Also, are you getting any script errors?

Comment: Yes, I do this in `$(document).ready()`...
Also , how can I check for script errors on device? I do not see any errors on desktop browser...

Comment: Instead of setting the event using attr, I will suggest use bind method. Also, as the element is added to DOM after the page is ready, you will need to use live method for that. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am using `$().on()` as I use `jQuery 1.7.2` But still its not working... What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of code:

```
function createList(list){
    var parentID = $("#content_nav ul");
    var len = list.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var anchorElement = jQuery('<a />',{text:list[i].text});
        var liElement = jQuery('<li />',{"class":"navlink_"+(i+1),id:"navlink_"+(i+1)});
        //anchorElement.attr('onclick',list[i].fnctn+"()"); - Works fine on desktop browsers but doesn't work on mobile devices. (Mobile devices are my target platform

        // append the target first

        liElement.append(anchorElement);
        parentID.append(liElement);

        // after append then bind the
        // click event

        anchorElement.on('click',{funct:list[i].fnctn},function(event) {
            return window[event.data.funct](event);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this one should do it